# Powering and dimming white LED from single-cell 3.7 rechargeable lithium battery (with a 3.3V Arduino mini)

Tags: led, battery-operated, led-driver, lipo

I'm designing a circuit for a handheld project that runs from a 1-cell rechargeable Lithium battery (18650 or prismatic). The circuit powers an Arduino Mini Pro running at 3.3VDC.

The Arduino board contains logic to:

1. operate a miniature 3V DC motor through PWM using a low power H bridge (dual-channel L9110S - only 1 channel used);
2. operate a red LED through PWM;
3. operate a white LED through PWM;
4. go into deep sleep and periodically blink a red LED when battery level is too low (below 3.5V).

The circuit also foresees the possibility to recharge the built-in Lithium battery by means of a USB charger (through a mini / micro / type C connector).

I designed the **functional prototype** with an Arduino nano running at 5VDC, so I could even power the white LED from the output pins. And that works flawlessly.

Porting everything to **3.3VDC** and **single-cell Lithium battery power**, things get more complicated.

Powering the red LED will probably still work, either directly or by using a switching transistor driven by the PWM signal (works with BC547B).

Powering the **white LED** won't work out of the box as the forward voltage is in the 3-4V range. Even with a switching transistor, I'll be out of luck.

I tried looking for step-up (boost) DC-DC converters and LED driver ICs, but they're either over-dimensioned (I only need approximately 500mA), or they don't support (or like) variable load, or they overheat with very low load, or they can't be sourced unless by the 1,000s. Some chips that have an **EN** pin allowing in principle to be operated through PWM are the B6288 from various brands and the [MT3608](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/977/DOC002977116.pdf) (Aerosemi) which seems to be the same. They're found in inexpensive buck-boost and boost converters such as [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33029072332.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.7.40b56e80Ocwbwx&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.14976.158757.0&scm_id=1007.14976.158757.0&scm-url=1007.14976.158757.0&pvid=49c576da-9c48-4157-b74d-72eb0f0fc069&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.14976.158757.0,pvid:49c576da-9c48-4157-b74d-72eb0f0fc069,tpp_buckets:668%230%23170098%233_668%23808%235965%23516_668%23888%233325%2311_4976%230%23158757%230_4976%232711%237538%23851_668%232846%238113%23673_668%232717%237565%23721).

So far I have also seen LED driver ICs with built-in charge pumps (e.g. the MAX8822, TPS61085 - see Fig. 20 on the data sheet). The circuitry they need is rather complex so I sense I'm over engineering things.

My initial plan was to power the Arduino by means of a Mini 360 DC/DC step-down converter. It is based on the LM2596 which has a duty cycle of max. 90%, which translates to a 10% input voltage dropout. In this setup I will be able to use 60-80% of the battery capacity at most.

Another option would be to first boost the input voltage to 5VDC (would solve the white LED voltage issue) and then use a buck converter to power the 3.3V electronics. It even appears that there are 5VDC boost modules that have a built-in battery charger circuit (I suppose they're used in 1-cell power banks). These combined boost/charger modules seem to require a 5V 1A power supply for charging.

How could (or should) I approach the LED powering and dimming in this setup?

Comment: What's wrong with using an over-spec'ed boost converter?

Comment: What I found so far is that either the over-spec'ed boost converter is too bulky (the project is a small handheld control box with a joystick for operating the motor and the LEDs). Or they don't like or support low or variable loads (e.g. low PWM duty cycle).

Comment: Do you actually need +500ma and -500ma?

Comment: I need approximately 500mA. I’ll update my question.

Comment: Honestly, personally, I would consider whether the white LED could be replaced with a green one.

Comment: The white LED is a “panic light” so it won’t help if it’s monochromatic green. A white LED is really very desirable.

Comment: I tried clarifying the 2 power scenarios I found so far in my question. The issue is that powering the LEDs, powering the Arduino and charging the LiPo cell are "interconnected" problems. I'll probably have to address them all at once.